# React js Second call to API request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a newbie in React Js and I'm having an issue with a button behaviour.

This is my class, which basically shows a label and an "empty" button.

```js
 class NotificationsMenuTitle extends React.Component {  
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.emptyNotifications = this.emptyNotifications.bind(this);
  }

  emptyNotifications(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.emptyNotifications();
  }

  render(){
    const { formatMessage } = this.props.intl;
    return (
      <div className="notifications-menu__list__title">
        <p>{formatMessage(labels.notifications)}</p>
        <SmallButton
          className="notifications-menu__list__title__emptyButton"
          actionType="confirm"
          onClick={this.emptyNotifications}>
          {formatMessage(labels.empty)}
        </SmallButton>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const SmartEmptyNotifications = connect(props => ({
  emptyNotifications: notificationRequests.emptyNotifications
}))(injectIntl(NotificationsMenuTitle));

export default SmartEmptyNotifications;
```

My request looks like this :

```
const notificationRequests = {
  emptyNotifications: () => ({
    emptyNotifications: {
      url: `${ENDPOINT_URL}/notification/all`,
      method: "DELETE",
      body: JSON.stringify()
}})};
```

When clicking on the "empty" button, I do my API request which does what it's suppose to do with no problem. 
The second time, I click on the button, I systematically get an error in the browser console => `TypeError: this.props.emptyNotifications is not a function` and my API request is not sent.

Do I need to "reset" the emptyNotifications somehow, so that I can call it more than once ? I feel that the "fulfilled: true" is the issue, but I do not know

This is what my this.props.emptyNotifications looks like on the second call :

```
emptyNotifications: {…}​​
   fulfilled: true
   meta: Object { request: Request, response: Response, component: undefined }
   pending: false​​
   reason: null​​
   refreshing: false​​
   rejected: false​​
   settled: true​​
   value: 1​​
   __proto__: Object { then: then(), catch: _catch(), … }
```

Thanks for any help you may to bring me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alexandr suggested, I was overwriting my own function. To fix this issue, I used a fetch instead of a promise (I hadn't really understood the difference between the two).

My emptyNotifications function now looks like :

```
emptyNotifications(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   const headers = makeHeadersForRequest();
   fetch(`${ENDPOINT_URL}/notifications/all`, {
     method: 'delete',
     headers: headers,
   }).then(response =>
     response.json().then(json => {
     return json;
   })
);}
```

And this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Look's like  you somehow reassign notificationRequests.emptyNotifications  to promise  which was returned after first request.

Comment: const notificationRequests = {
  emptyNotifications: () => ({
    emptyNotifications: {
      url: `${ENDPOINT_URL}/notification/all`,
      method: "DELETE",
      body: JSON.stringify()
}})};


I don't see here api call just  config for it. I think you  didn't place here some  code which do api call

Comment: Yes, it is just the config. I have a global mecanism for the API requests, and as I said in my post, the first call to the API works perfectly as it should.

Comment: But yes, I have unfortunately reassigned notificationRequests.emptyNotifications. Thanks.

Comment: How do I make sure I don't reassign my emptyNotifications function ?

Comment: I think you can check your  mechanism for the API requests (I think issue can be in it) or  provide it here. Also you can simply  do  few requests  on same endpoint and check result.